# Reserved bit meaning

Tags: linux, bit

In the file http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.4/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L29, there are some information about page fault error code:

```
Page fault error code bits:
bit 0 ==    0: no page found       1: protection fault
bit 1 ==    0: read access         1: write access
bit 2 ==    0: kernel-mode access  1: user-mode access
bit 3 ==                           1: use of reserved bit detected
bit 4 ==                           1: fault was an instruction fetch
```

In the case "bit 3" "1: use of reserved bit detected", which are the possible scenario that can make kernel set this bit to 1? Is there any documents about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*Reserved* bits in data structures are those that have some special meaning and are used internally.

Bit 3 of error code in in your example will be set if any *reserved* bits in paging-related data structures were modified by your code. E.g. in 4 Mb page directory entries on x86 bits 21 through 12 are *reserved* for use by system and overwriting them is an error.

Comment: @Naruto That's bad but I don't think we can help you with that's not enough infromation. Probably you've got a broken kernel module or something is wrong with your RAM.

Comment: @Naruto What do you mean by “with my driver”? Are you debugging your own kernel module? Anyway, this seems to be a separate question.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible diagnose such a problem remotely. Most likely you are simply corrupting memory somewhere around page directory.